# Fetch gives back an Internal Server Error while Postman accepts it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

In Postman I call a request to an API with success.

When I try this using `fetch()` in ReactJS it gives back an `Internal Server Error (500)`

My Fetch looks like:

```
const FetchData = async (url , request) => {
    return await fetch(url, request)
    .then(async function(res) {
        if (res.ok)
            console.log("OK: " + await res.json())
        else
            console.log("NOT OK: " + await res.text())
    });
}
```

Request:

```
{
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
  body: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Postman > body:

```
{
    "value": {
        "RequestType":1,
        "Dependencies":[],
        "Priority":1,
        "RequestLocation":"some string",
        "RequestJSON": "some string",
        "NoCache":true,
        "PostNow":true,
        "Authentication": {
            "Email":"string",
            "Device": {
                "Name":"string",
                "UniqueDeviceId":"string",
                "AppVersion":"string",
                "AppType":int,
                "Devicestatus":int
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm 100% sure that both body's are equal to each other.

I cannot find out what the problem is. Do yousee it?

Comment: did you try adding headers specifying the data is in JSON format? like this: `headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }`

Comment: @AlonYampolski Si. ;)

Comment: can you share the postman request that works (even if it's with fake data)?

Comment: Right click the request in the network panel of the developer tools and convert it to a cURL request.  You should be able to convert the Postman request to a cURL command as well.  Compare these 2 converted commands and note the differences.

Comment: What does the error 500 say exactly?

Comment: @MrLine I also see that in your code you didn't specify that you're using the `POST` method while fetching the data

Comment: @AlonYampolski the updated version has it

Comment: @theshadog I get an FaultException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) will send the `body` as is, in your case you are sending a JS object, not JSON data i.e.

```
body: { ... }
```

If the server is expects JSON data then you will need to convert your object to a JSON string i.e.

```
body: JSON.stringify({ ... })
```

*P.S. it's worth noting that this has probably highlighted a lack of validation on your server-side for invalid requests, you might want to fix that.*